# Item creation issue. 503 error

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-form, postback

I am facing below problem in one of the list.

So, I have list with 12k items. Throttling disabled.

Problem appears whenever I try to create or edit list item. Item gets created successfully, but form does not redirect me to list view. Form keeps loading for 1.7 min and then blank page appears.

In chrome network tab I can see 503 error. I can't find much info in ULS logs.

[image]

Comment: Try creating a view which contains less than 5K items, and make it default. Check again after adding/editing an item whether it redirects to view correctly or not.